# Indexing into Pandas multi-index DF with non-continuous list index selections

Tags: python, indexing, pandas, dataframe

I am organizing my data into a multi-index df that looks something like this:

```
In [8]: data
Out[8]:
                    Time     Primary  Secondary    BL LED
Sweep
Sweep0001 0      0.00000  -70.434570 -41.656494 -0.000305
          1      0.00005  -67.626953 -41.625977  0.000305
          2      0.00010  -68.725586 -41.595459 -0.002441
          3      0.00015  -70.556641 -41.625977  0.000305
          4      0.00020  -71.899414 -41.442871 -0.002136
...                  ...         ...        ...       ...
Sweep0010 79970  3.99850 -105.102539 -41.351318 -0.001221
          79971  3.99855  -96.801758 -41.534424  0.000000
          79972  3.99860 -105.712891 -41.687012  0.000305
          79973  3.99865 -109.741211 -41.473389 -0.001221
          79974  3.99870 -106.567383 -41.503906 -0.000610

[800000 rows x 4 columns]
```

I need to be able to select an arbitrary combination of Sweeps (e.g. Sweep0002, Sweep0005, Sweep0007). Ideally, I would be able to pass a list of the sweeps that I want to select.

I can select a range of sweeps using `.ix` as long as they are continuous. e.g.:

```
In [9]: data.ix['Sweep0001':'Sweep0003']
Out[9]:
                    Time    Primary  Secondary    BL LED
Sweep
Sweep0001 0      0.00000 -70.434570 -41.656494 -0.000305
          1      0.00005 -67.626953 -41.625977  0.000305
          2      0.00010 -68.725586 -41.595459 -0.002441
          3      0.00015 -70.556641 -41.625977  0.000305
          4      0.00020 -71.899414 -41.442871 -0.002136
...                  ...        ...        ...       ...
Sweep0003 79970  3.99850 -93.139648 -41.595459 -0.000610
          79971  3.99855 -88.378906 -41.381836 -0.002747
          79972  3.99860 -93.750000 -41.534424  0.000610
          79973  3.99865 -93.261719 -41.381836  0.000000
          79974  3.99870 -93.139648 -41.473389  0.000610

[240000 rows x 4 columns]
```

However, I cannot figure out a way to select a non-continuous range / list of sweeps.

I've resorted to looping through a list of sweeps and constructing a new df of the selected sweeps, which is obviously not an ideal solution. i.e.:

```
sweep_list = ['Sweep0001', 'Sweep0003', 'Sweep0009']
df_list = [data.ix[sweep] for sweep in sweep_list]

sub_df = pd.concat(df_list, keys=sweep_list)
sub_df.index.levels[0].name = "Sweep"
```

There must be a better way to go about doing this, but I can't seem to figure out what that is.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just do `df.ix[['Sweep0001', 'Sweep0003', 'Sweep0009']]`?

Comment: gah...i swear i had tried doing just that and it hadn't worked, but yes, that does work.